# Reliable method for detecting when a USB HID device is emulating a keyboard

Tags: c, embedded, usb, hid

I'm working on an embedded system, and I need to determine if the user has connected an HID device emulating a keyboard (i.e. a barcode scanner) or an actual keyboard.

I can inspect the iManufacturer, iProduct, iSerialNumber, and iInterface string descriptors to gain some clues.  For example, "reader" or "scanner" has been observed to appear in the iProduct string when a barcode reader has been connected.  Likewise, "emulation" has been seen in the iInterface string.  However, I'm a bit reluctant to rely solely on these strings (string case is easy enough to handle, but handling things like abbreviations in key words/phrases quickly becomes onerous.)

I've reviewed the USB 1.10 and 1.11 specs and found that the Report descriptor offers some cues, as well.  For example, the Global Usage item should be something like 0x0501 for Generic Desktop, and the Local Usage item should be 0x0906 (Keyboard).  Is there anything else in the Report descriptor that might assist in detecting the difference?

I would like to avoid relying on the Vendor ID and Product ID lists since this is an embedded system with limited resources.  Suggestions? Is there something I've missed?

Comment: Have you taken a look how say Linux deals with something like this?

Comment: I don't believe Linux has a need to disambiguate a keyboard and something pretending to be a keyboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no absolutely reliable method to do this.  There cannot be, because there is no absolute definition of what is or is not a keyboard -- nor of what the difference is between "emulating a keyboard" and "being a keyboard".  The boundary gets particularly fuzzy around assistive devices and things like chording keyboards, but even beyond that, you have the fundamental problem that the way to emulate a keyboard is to communicate across the USB cable in exactly the way that a keyboard communicates.

The methods you've suggested are reasonable heuristics for identifying a number of things that are clearly non-keyboards (with a faint risk of false positives in some cases), but heuristics that look for hints are the best solution that's going to be possible.

Comment: I'm in complete agreement.  My question was a last-ditch effort to find a more robust solution.  Thanks!